# deploy google analytics to single html page not in root directory

Tags: html, google-analytics

I have created an html page specifically for facebook page and I need google analytics tracking for that page.

The page I have created is does not reside on root directory, instead the root directory is currently empty and I have added another folder for the html page. Now I have added the google anaytics code to the html file, but google anaytics reports

> tracking not installed

How do I overcome this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by looking at some of the answers in Google Analytics forum it looks like there a couple things that could be the problems.

- Incorrect script, you can correct this by clicking "Edit" and then "Check status" to get proper UA and script
- Time delay, apparently sometimes it takes up to 24 hours to see results of tracking
- Change default home page under "Profile settings" and ensure that your homepage has a trailing "/"

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=5bd936ef9dcb807b&hl=en
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=60e0b7aa62ca25aa&hl=en
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=0bbbafc53f9bc417&hl=en

Comment: I already had a trailing "/". It has something to do public_html being empty and my content being in public_html/fb. There might be someway to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore that message just go to the page and refresh a few times. Once data has been sent you will be fine.